# Python - Problem multiple "or" conditions in a if statement for gcode modifier

Tags: python, g-code

I am working on a script to modify some gcode for a school project. My programming skills are very poor but I am working on this with the help of the internet, but go stuck on a if statement with 3 different options.

I need for this to select the lines that start with "G0" and "G1" and respect the length condition.

with just 2 conditions is working fine (it creates an output file so I can confirm)

I've tried just adding the 3rd condition as I show bellow, but that retrieves an empty file - so I'm assuming that is not working (and this seems the correct way to do it as far as I researched).

```
if(cells[0] !="G0" or cells[0] != "G1" or len(cells) < 4):
    return
```

Complete Function:

```
class Point:
x = 0
y = 0
feed = 0

def GetPoint(line):
    line = line.rstrip("\n")
    cells = line.split(" ")
    point = Point()


if(cells[0] != "G1" or len(cells) < 4):
    return

if(cells[1].startswith("F")):
    point.feed = float(cells[1].split("F")[1])
    point.x = float(cells[2].split("X")[1])
    point.y = float(cells[3].split("Y")[1])

else:
    point.x = float(cells[1].split("X")[1])
    point.y = float(cells[2].split("Y")[1])

return point
```

Comment: Consider if `cells[0]` is `"G0"`, then your test `if cells[0] != "G1"` is TRUE.  You probably need `and` instead of `or`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your indentation is messed up. Could you please fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already answered, you have a condition that will always evaluate to true.  If you're wanting to extract all but the G0 and G1 commands (or the length condition) then try this

```
if not (cells[0] == "G0" or cells[0] == "G1") or len(cells) < 4:
```

This way you are checking whether cells[0] contains the G0 or G1 and then inverting the result. This can also be written as

```
if cells[0] != "G0" and cells[0] != "G1" or len(cells) < 4:
```

by De Morgan's Law but it might not be as intuitive.

Answer (score 4):

Note that in the first block, you have `cells[0] != "G0" or cells[0] != "G1"` as two of the conditions. If `cells[0]` is `"G0"`, then the second one will evaluate to `True`. If `cells[0]` is `"G1"`, then the first will evaluate to `True`. If it's anything else, both will evaluate to `True`. This means that no matter what the value of `cells[0]` is, the `if` will evaluate to `True`.

If it helps you think about it, write a truth table for the truthness/falseness of each condition and decide what you want the `if` statement to evaluate to.

Comment: Thanks Calvin! those details slipped me... now I understand why that does not work.